# Creating a load balancer for CloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is it possible to create a GCP Managed load balancer infront of a CloudSQL instance?

I have been checking the Google documentation, but don't see anything about this specific use case.  Also cannot assign a CloudSQL instance into an instance group, or backend group within GCP.

Would love if anyone had any insight to the possibility.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's an example of how do use HAProxy that may be useful:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/using-haproxy-to-scale-read-only-workloads-on-cloud-sql-for-postgresql